# How to segue with a UITableView using a coordinator?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Below is my view controller that segues to a different view controller using the coordinator:

```
import UIKit

class OrdersViewController: UIViewController, OrdersBaseCoordinated {
    
    var coordinator: OrdersBaseCoordinator?
    var goToOrders2button: UIButton!
    
    init(coordinator: OrdersBaseCoordinator) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        self.coordinator = coordinator
        title = "Orders"
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        configureButton()
    }
    
    private func configureButton() {
        goToOrders2button = UIButton()
        view.addSubview(goToOrders2button)
        goToOrders2button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        goToOrders2button.setTitle(" Go to Orders 2 ", for: .normal)
        goToOrders2button.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        goToOrders2button.layer.borderWidth = 2
        goToOrders2button.backgroundColor = .black
        goToOrders2button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(goToOrders2), for: .touchUpInside)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            goToOrders2button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            goToOrders2button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }
    
    @objc private func goToOrders2() {
        coordinator?.moveTo(flow: .orders(.secondScreen), userData: nil)
    }
}
```

How can I implement the same thing on a list of buttons in a UITableView as I don't want to create a separate button for each item in the list?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a protocol delegate like

```
protocol GoToOrdersDelegate {
   func onButtonClick()
}
```

Then on the cell have

```
weak var delegate: GoToOrdersDelegate?
```

Implement this delegate on your controller and pass self to your cell in UITableView

Then on the cell have your button call

```
delegate?.onButtonClick()
```

And have your coordinator in a single place

Comment: sorry if I was not clear before, so I wanted to do something like:

UITableView list has fruits like -> apple, banana, orange

when I click on them they should go to their own respective images, not sure how I can achieve this since I cannot do performSegue as I am not using storyboards